# How do define certain tests on certain branches?

Tags: r, unit-testing, yaml, gitlab-ci, testthat

I am new to gitlab ci/cd. i like how it works. I would like to run certain tests in certain branches. how can i define the same in yml file?

I am using gitlab ci/cd for R package development and using testthat package for unit-testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think how to structure your test suites in your branches.

For example, you can name test-suite like `/tests/branch_1/` and your branch has name `branch_1`, then

```
test_job:
  script:
    -  test_dir("inst/tests/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
```

where `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` is your branch or tag name, according to [gitlab predefined variables doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), will execute the test-suite with the same name your branch name is.